# Select from a list of objects where a value occurs more than once

Tags: python

I have a list of the below custom object in python. I want to create a new list of objects where the 'ledId' more than once (like a list of duplicates based on an id)

##### The object

```
class CustomObject:
    def __init__(self, id, ledId):
        self.id = id
        self.ledId = ledId
```

I usually use C# so I am wanting to do something like

```
var subList = myList.Where(obj => myList.Count(l => l.ledId == obj.ledId) > 1)
                     .ToList();
```

Is there an easy way to do this in python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I want to create a new list of objects where the 'ledId' more than once" I can't make any sense out of this - I think you accidentally left out some words. Please read [ask] and [mre] and show: an **exact** example of an input list (i.e., the code that creates some `CustomObject` instances), and the **exact** result that the code should have with that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting you code in C# to Python would be something like this:

```
[a for a in some_list if len([b for b in some_list if b.ledId == a.ledId]) > 1]
```

Comment: @primmslim but it's inefficient. This checks the whole list again for each item. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75578099/16343464) is more appropriate

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions will work, but for the record, the algorithm as presented here is in O(n^2), since you run the `count` for each iteration. You can make it O(n) by counting once, and storing the result in a `dict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)

for custom_object in sub_list:
    counts[custom_objects.ledId] += 1

result = [x for x in sub_list if counts[x.ledId] > 1]
```

It is also a great opportunity to use `defaultdict`, but you do lose the very functional approach from C#, to make it more "Pythonic".

Comment: In Python list comprehensions are preferred over list+filter (and usually faster).

Comment: Sure, I guess I used `filter` to keep it more "functional" looking, but I can edit to make it a list comprehension, it doesn't change much :)

Comment: You can use `collections.Counter`: count = `Counter({o.ledId for o in sub_list})`